# Install – Rule “Oracle JRE 7 Update 51 (64-bit) or higher is required” failed

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2017

When I try to Install SQL server 2017 in Windows Server 2016, i got this issue. then i install the Java JRE latest version but still got the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but, do you actually need [Polybase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide)? If you don't, then don't select it as part of the installation. If you do, did you download the file from the link the message provided (and ensure you installed the 64bit version, not the 32bit)? https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526030

Comment: yes Im using same link and when i uptick Polybase option it works, but when I tick that, gives same issue.

Comment: So, you *do* **need** PolyBase? (You didn't actually answer that).

Comment: Yes, That is why i checked and try to install.

Comment: @Larnu, It's an excellent answer! I had installed several versions of JRE all didn't work. I listened your advise and uncheck all irrelevant items. It passes!